# Citealias doesn't follow the same rules for parenthesis

Tags: citing, natbib, citetalias

I am trying to cite an organization, but the command `\citepalias` doesn't work the same as `\citep`, it removes parenthesis.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{fao1990,
    author = {{Food and Agriculture Organization}},
    title = {FAO soils bulletin},
    publisher = {FAO},
    year = {1990}  
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,authoryear]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks, hidelinks, colorlinks, linktocpage=false, pagebackref=true, breaklinks=false]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=Darkgreen,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=BlueViolet%cyan!50!black!90
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\begin{document}
\defcitealias{fao1990}{FAO, 1990} 
\citepalias{fao1990}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When I run your code (with `\bibliographystyle{apa}` changed into `\bibliography{apalike}`) then I get parentheses around the `\citepalias` output, which is as expected. With `\citetalias` there are no parentheses, this is also expected. The alias does not know that `1990` is a year, the alias is just a plain string without structure. You could define `FAO, (1990)` as alias to use with `\citetalias`, but then `\citepalias` will have double parentheses, i.e., (FAO, (1990)). If you want something similar to your screenshot [...]

Comment: [...] then it might be easier to use FAO as author in the `.bib` file and Food and Agriculture Organization and publisher, and then just use `\citep` and `\citet`.